# Diferença entre $(window) e $(document)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe alguma diferença entre usar o `$(window) e $(document)`?

Porque pelo que eu encontrei eles fazem a mesma coisa....

E essa inicialização:

```
$(window).on('ready load resize', function(){
```

Funcionaria se fosse assim?

```
$(document).on('ready load resize', function(){
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### $(window)

O objeto `$(window)` se refere à janela, viewport do navegador que está executando o site. Com ele é possível capturar as dimensões da janela, o quanto o usuário usou o scroll, etc.
Com esse objeto, você pode executar código quando **toda** a página estiver carregada, incluindo imagens, scripts, estilos e afins. Ou seja, o código só será executado quando tudo estiver concluído. Exemplo:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  alert("Página carregada!"); // Esse alert só irá aparecer quando a página estiver completamente carregada
});
```

---

### $(document)

Diferente do `$(window)`, o objeto `$(document)` tem referência ao *documento* como um todo. Esse documento a qual me refiro é o DOM, todos os elementos da página (código HTML). Esse é o mais utilizado, pois o script rodará **imediatamente** após os elementos carregarem, independente das imagens e estilos. Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert("DOM carregado!"); // Esse alert irá aparecer imediatamente após o DOM ser carregado
};
```

O código acima também pode ser escrito dessas outras formas:

```
$(function() {
  alert("DOM carregado!"); // Esse alert irá aparecer imediatamente após o DOM ser carregado
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  alert("DOM carregado!"); // Esse alert irá aparecer imediatamente após o DOM ser carregado
});

$(document).on('ready', function() {
  alert("DOM carregado!"); // Esse alert irá aparecer imediatamente após o DOM ser carregado
});
```

### Referências

Páginas muito interessantes para você ler:

- https://api.jquery.com/load-event/
- https://api.jquery.com/ready/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683072/jquery-events-load-ready-unload
- https://forum.jquery.com/topic/document-ready-and-window-onload-difference
- http://jquerybrasil.org/diferenca-entre-window-load-e-document-ready/